# 2005 Honda Civic Instrument Panel loose connection. PCB issue?

Tags: honda, civic

My instrument panel has an issue where it loses power completely but shows the handbrake light. It usually happens when the weather is cold outside or it rains. When I use either the left or right indicator the instrument panel flickers and even comes back on sometimes. After taking it out, I realized that it comes on when I apply downward pressure/ put pressure towards me on the green connector side. I checked the connections of the connector pins to the PCB and they seem to be fine. I cant see and cracks on the PCB which might cause any issue. I figured that since it happens only when its cold, some thing must be contracting and causing a break in connection. Any one have any insight on how to fix this?

Comment: Since this question seems to be highly model specific, i'd suggest asking this question on a Honda specific forum. You might find people there that can tell you if this is a common problem and how it can be fixed,

Comment: I’d check pin fit on the connector